# Does it need to DeleteObject after CBrush ()

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Does DeleteObject need to be called after CBrush ()

Does it is need to call `deleteObject() if CBrush bNewBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not have to manually call it. The destructor of CBrush calls DeleteObject() for you...actually the destructor for CGdiObject from which CBrush is derived.

To make sure bad things don't happen, you should also make sure that the brush is not selected into a device context when the destruction occurs.

Answer (score 0):

no, you can find in the msdn an exemple of code.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/btwwha51.aspx